# UITableViewController vs UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 Controllers within one app as I am trying out these different settings.

One is a UITableViewController which the way I understand has the Delegate and the Datasource are drawn from the Superclass.

Now going by that theory I now also have a UIViewController with a UITableView on it and in the header file I have declared the Datasource and the Delegate.

So far so Good:-)

Now this is the bit I do not get:

In the implementation file I can use the tableView pointer to link data, but I am using Core Data and I have this piece of code amongst others:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  {   
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  }
```

This and 5 other situations give an error on the UIViewController if I do not setup a

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Of course it is synthesized:-)

But if I declare this tableView I get a warning for a double up on the line that says this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

because it also declares a tableView.

So I have 2 questions:

1) Why do I have to set the IBOutlet if I have set a UITableViewDatasource and Delegate?

2) If I give the UITableViewCell a different pointer name - like tableView2, why can I not see the changes upon editing the data, but only see the result after relaunching the app?

The MasterViewController, which is the UITableViewController has not got this option.

Cheers Jeff

---ADDING IMAGES----

[image]

[image]

---

To get into edit mode i have this code in the viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

and I use this code to action what needs to be done:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}   
}
```

Now the + option works, but I only see the result after I relaunch the app. I can swipe and delete, but again it does not animate live within the same instance of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a property called tableView and presumably just synthesized it with the same name.

`UITableViewController` also has a property called tableView, but the backing ivar will be called something different, probably `_tableView`, precisely because the default tableview datasource and delegate methods usually pass in an argument called `tableView` which, in the scope of the method, is clashing with your instance variable.

Inside that method, what does `tableView` mean? The argument that was passed in, or your ivar?

In answer to your specific questions:

1. You need the outlet for those instances when your view controller needs to talk to the table view (like when you tell it to begin updates). The datasource and delegate connections are there for when the table view needs to talk to your view controller (like when it asks for a cell).
2. I'm not sure what you are asking here, you can call the outlet to the table view anything you like but you must also alter everything that sends messages to `self.tableView`. For consitency I would synthesize the property like so:

   ```
   @synthesize tableView = _tableview;
   ```

   This prevents an ivar called `tableView` existing in the first place. I am assuming you haven't declared the ivar, and have only declared the property as an IBOutlet?:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
   ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply 1) I have declared the ivar and then set a property to it match that. 2) I guess to simplify the question, if I set the TableView Delegates and Datasource in the header file, why does that not come with the tableView argument? 3) I have tried the _tableView way to synthesize, but that has the same effect as when I change the "cellForRowAtIndexPath:" to a tableView2. 4) When I add and edit the UITableViewController the results are animated e.g. the delete sign comes in the display, this does not happen when I rename the UITableView in the View Controller.

Comment: Sorry that was a long comment, just trying to clarify your questions with my explanations;-)

Comment: You may need to include more code in your question. 1) Don't do that, remove the ivar declaration as I suggest. 2) I don't know what you mean by this, pleas show the relevant code 3) you need to include the code you currently have 4) see 3). How are you connecting your view controller to the table view, and how are you connecting the table view's datasource and delegate to the view controller?

Comment: Ok I have deleted the ivar, sorry I misunderstood that and it has gotten rid off the warnings and edits:-) However the live editing of the TableView is still not happening - it is in the background, but I cannot see it until the relaunch of the app. I have added a screen shot to show you what I mean, the UI is not pretty yet, but the point comes across I hope.

Comment: How are you setting the table view to edit mode in the view controller?

Comment: You've accepted the answer, are you asking a separate question about the deleting or have you solved it?

Comment: No still working on that, sorry for the confusion - Just a lot of your tips have helped already. Essentially the UITableView (with the blue) is not showing live results.

Comment: ok, i got a step further. I have put both views in a tab bar, so I can switch between them. The TVC (TableViewController) is the first screen. Any edits made on that before I tab over to the other screen are reflected. After I switch and switch back to number 1, the edits I make then are not reflected in the other until I restart the app.

Comment: You should ask a new question, this one is a bit of a mess now. I think the problem is in your various fetched results controller delegate methods, they are either incorrect or you haven't set the delegate.